# apple software is not working in the app store

Tags: macos, applications, software-update, login

I cannot update my updates in the apps store for apple
the user id is locked (untitled projects@gmail.com)

I understand why the id field is locked under this user id

How can I resolve this issue I have a 15 in Mac Book Pro using OS X 10.10.5

thank you,
Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy, sometime Apple blocks some account for security reasons.
So go to [iForgot](https://iforgot.apple.com/) and insert your Apple ID.
There you can unlock or reset you Apple ID password (I recommend to reset).

For more details, here's the official article [If your Apple ID is locked](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204106)